# I cant seem to be able to display the name for the students properly?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I had asked for help but you guys helped me and I figured it out how to obtain the grades from the file.

This was my initial problem.

Assignment: Download the file gradeBook.txt available through D2l. The file contains an unknown number of students.

this is whats in the text file:

Melanie 84 Danielle Marie 90 Nicolas Raul 87 Michael 67 Joshua 46 Alexis Michelle 90 Jared M. 55 Andres Gabriel 78 Pierre Louis 80 Charles 60 Cin Lian 95 Carlos Manuel 81

Information for each student is displayed in two lines:

 The first line indicates the name of the student – whitespaces are allowed.

 The second line shows the student’s grade in a class. Write a program that prompts the user for the name of the file and displays a nicely formatted report showing:

a. Student with the highest grade in the class – Name and grade

b. Student with the lowest grade in the class – Name and grade

c. Average grade in the class

This was the updated code, however, now I can't seemt  display the names properly it only displays the last name and the second students it doesnt even diplay it??? Can someone please help me??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream gFile;
    int choice, grades;
    string gb, students, highestStudent;
    do {
        cout << "Student Grade Book Info Program....\n";
        cout << "\tPlease Select an Option: (1 or 2) \n" << endl
            << "\t1. Review Grades"
            << "\n\t2. Quit"
            << "\n\tChoose: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
            cout << "\n\tPlease Enter the Name of the File you wish to View the Grades for: " << endl;
            cout << "\n\tAvailable Grade Books: gradeBook\n" <<
                "\tType in the Grade Book you would like to view. ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, gb);

            if (gb == "gradeBook") {

                gFile.open("gradeBook.txt", ios::in);

                if (gFile) {

                    cout << "\t" << setw(20) << left << "Student"
                        << setw(30) << left << "Grade";

                    int counter = 0;
                    int highest = 0;
                    int lowest = 100;
                    string lowestStudent;
                    while (gFile >> students) {

                        getline(gFile, students);
                        gFile >> grades;

                        do {
                            if (grades < lowest) {
                                lowest = grades;
                                lowestStudent = students;

                            }

                            if (highest < grades) {
                                highest = grades;
                                highestStudent = students;
                            }

                        } while (grades > highest);
                    }
                    counter++;

                    cout << highestStudent << endl;
                    cout << highest << endl;
                    cout << lowestStudent << endl;
                    cout << lowest << endl;

                    cout << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\tError... Could open gradeBook.txt ";
                    return 5;
                }

            }
            else {
                cout << "\n\tError there is no such entry in the system.\n" << endl;

            }

        case 2:
            break;
        }

    } while (choice != 2);


    return 0;
}
```